# VBA Filtering Out (AutoFilter)

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a VBA macro for filtering out values in one column. This column is the first column in my worksheet. I want to filter out values starting with "158" and "258" for a 6 digit code and I want to filter out these values for the code as well: 370006 and 181023.

I keep getting the following error: "Syntax error"

I tried the following:

```
Sub FilterMacro()
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$21").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=">=158000", _
Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2="<159000", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria3:=">=258000", _
Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria4="<259000", Operator:=xlOr, Criteria4:="37006", _
Operator:=xlOr, Criteria5:="181023"
End Sub
```

I am new to VBA. This is my first VBA attempt and I do not understand what the underscores mean or if I am using that correctly. Also for the range, I would like not specify an exact row amount as the rows can differ during each month where I would like to run this VBA macro.

Edit: Also any tips with doing multiple criterias for filtering since AutoFilter only does two criterias will be much appreciated too.

Any help appreciated! If you see the syntax errors too, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: [`AutoFilter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.autofilter) only has `Criteria1` and `Criteria2` parameters, no more than that. You can only have one `Operator` parameter as well.

Comment: `$A$1:$G:$21` has an extra `:`.

Comment: Thanks, I corrected for that, but still getting synax issues. Also apologies for the formatting. I am not sure how to format the code when posting here. And thank you! Didn't realize AutoFilter only had two criterias.

Comment: `Filed:=1` >> `Field:=1`